# How to create Segue which make view controller fullscreen in Xcode 11.1

Tags: swift, xcode, segue

When I try to create segue via storyboard it's only does open new view controller as pop out instead of fullscreen. I tried changing kind of segue from ,,Show (e.g. Push)" to others but then I get "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you need to do is set the destination view controller's `modalPresentationStyle` to `fullscreen` by way of `prepareForSegue:sender:`:

```swift
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    ...

    @IBAction func segueButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

        if let secondViewController = segue.destination as? SecondViewController {
            secondViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        }
    }
}
```

`prepareForSegue:sender:` is called before a segue is performed from a `UIViewController`. The default `modalPresentationStyle` in iOS 13+ is `.pageSheet`, which is the presentation that **doesn't** cover the whole screen (though it allows for more natural navigation/dismissal via swiping the view controller down and off the screen). We need to change this `modalPresentationStyle` to `.fullScreen` before performing the segue.

Answer (score 16):

You need to select `present modally` for the `segue type` and then right below select the presentation style `full screen`:

[image: Xcode shot]

Comment: This fixes it without touching the code :)