# How do I get it so my previous view doesn't show up behind my new view in the Xcode Simulator

Tags: swift, xcode, segue

So currently I'm coding an app, and I want to segue from one view to a new view, but every time I use the segue the old view is seen in the background of the new view, like so.
[image: As you can see at the top the previous view is seen behind]

It should also be noted that on the simulator I can just drag downward and the view goes away, I don't really want this to happen either.

On the storyboard for the attributes inspector, I'm using identifier: FadeSegue, class: FadeSegue, Selector: none, and Kind: Custom

Here's what the code implementing the segue looks like:
In the viewDidLoad function:

```
let cTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(shiftView(_:)))
view.addGestureRecognizer(cTap)
```

the shiftView function:

```
@objc func shiftView(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "FadeSegue", sender: nil)
}
```

Then the FadeSegue animation code (I'm pretty sure the issue doesn't come from this)

```
import UIKit


class FadeSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform() {
        let source = self.source
        let destination = self.destination

        let transition = CATransition()
        transition.type = CATransitionType.fade
        transition.duration = 0.7

        source.view.window?.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)

        source.present(destination, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you guys see anything wrong.

With this code I was expecting the new view to simply completely replace the old view by fading in. The fade animation does work, but you can still see the old view behind the new one, and you can still swipe down to get rid of the new view.

Comment: The is the default representation of a modal view, and the drag to close is also the default behaviour.  I'd suggest working through some of the more recent UIKit tutorials to get a better understanding of such things and how to customise the defaults.  It may also be worth checking whether your view hierarchy is embedded in a navigation controller.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create Segue which make view controller fullscreen in Xcode 11.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58507034/how-to-create-segue-which-make-view-controller-fullscreen-in-xcode-11-1)